# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training' has no attribute '_disallow_inside_tf_function'

Tags: python, conda, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am trying to develop a chatbot with rasa, and when I run rasa init to train the bot I have this error. I have TensorFlow 2.3.2, Keras 2.3.1, python 3.8.5.
I don't know if there is a compatibility problem. I am trying also to use a virtual environment.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training' has no attribute '_disallow_inside_tf_function'
```

Comment: Please provide some snap shots..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which rasa version are you using? It would also be helpful if you could provide the full stacktrace.

I also had a look at the Rasa `poetry.lock` [file](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/poetry.lock), the latest rasa version should work with tensorflow 2.3.2, python 3.8.5, `keras-preprocessing` should be 1.1.2. If you want to use rasa with all its dependencies, you could try `pip3 install rasa[full]` as stated in the [docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation#additional-dependencies).

Please note that if you want to train a model, you should run [`rasa train`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/command-line-interface/#rasa-train) command, instead of `rasa init`.